# How to close a called class using JFrame without closing the class that called it?

Tags: java

I seem to have a fairly unique problem, and I searched for a while for an answer on here without finding one. I have a class that has a simple JFrame with two buttons. Each button calls the Main method of a different class, as such:

```
checkRuling = new JButton("Check Your Deck's Rulings");
  checkRuling.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        ReadHtmlCardDatabase.main(null);
     }
  });
```

One calls a class that takes a series of inputs into a text field and creates a formatted html document from the inputs, and the other loads the html document into a JEditorPane. My problem is that when I close one of the JFrames for the subclasses (either the input or html loader one), it exits my program completely, and I want to keep the main class (with the two buttons) open. I've tried using:

```
close = new JButton("CLOSE");
     close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
          System.exit(1);
        }
     });
```

On a button in the subclasses, to no avail. When the button is clicked it simply exits everything. I've also tried using:

```
JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_EXIT
```

For the subclasses, but this causes the JFrames to go away without the subclasses actually closing, so the first one that saves the html document never actually saves it, and the second subclass that opens that same html document won't work, because it wasn't saved. Any help would be appreciated, because I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: For the sake of not having 700 lines of code on here, I'll paste more of the code if it's needed to answer the question, but I know SOverflow prefers to not have a bajillion lines of pasted, irrelevant code. Sorry if I didn't include enough of it.

Comment: I believe it can be done with SecurityManager

Comment: Create a new instance, as in Classname c = new Classname() and then just do c.main(null) as the actionevent?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I'll research that, thanks.

Comment: @velvetxcat I'm guessing the reason you have `.main(null)` is because they're pre-existing programs, right?

Comment: The call to `main()` smells. I suppose those are classes that were designed to work on their own, hence they have EXIT_ON_CLOSE on their JFrames, or something like that. So you should refactor such that their behavior will be slightly different when used independently and when used as objects.

Comment: Bingo to both the above. The programs work as standalones and as part of this bigger one, because of the functions they perform as life point calculators and rulings table-builders for yugioh players. I will consider the feedback I've gotten, though. Using JWIndow as Ashakura suggested and reworking as @RealSkeptic suggested are both really helpful things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Fast Snail says in the comments, you shouldn't be calling a main method. Instantiate a class that does each functonality. Set the frame to visible using `setVisible(true)` when you start using it, then `setVisible(false)` when you're done. So, in the action listener, just change the visibility.

Then, assuming you don't have anything too wild going on, the frame you just set to invisible should go out of scope and get freed so that memory isn't chewed up. You just instantiate a new copy of the `ReadHtmlCardDatabase` class each time you need one. Or you could have one static copy that you set visible/invisible as needed.

Comment: Thank you! I just figured this out thanks to you and Fast Snail. Now it works perfectly <3 I just couldn't use the setvisible to false because I have to actually exit the class that writes the html file to be able to view it with the reader, but the approach is good.

Comment: Now, a couple of notes: as Asakura stated, you definitely should only be using one JFrame. I'm overlooking that because you have more important priorities, like learning how the code works, before you get into nitpicky details. HOWEVER, I really think you should take some time to read through the official Java Swing tutorials before you go any further. You don't want to get any bad habits and have to break them later, and I can already see a few troubling things here, namely the multiple JFrame issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, mate. I appreciate it, and I'll take a look. Having multiple JFrames in this case is actually something that I need to have because of the way my overall program is set up. It's actually a tool for Yu-Gi-Oh players, and it's pretty much a toolbox thing, so having it all onscreen at once would be a big issue. It's sort of like a mini-os with a bunch of little apps. Any way you can think of to do that without having a bunch of JFrames popping up and down would be super appreciated, though!

Answer (score 0):

> one of the JFrames

You should use only one JFrame in Your GUI. For other windows You can use for example JDialog or JWindow.
This should help, if not You can always use `frame.setVisible(false)` instead of dispose on close, but it' s not very neat.

Comment: I'll look into using JWindow, that seems like it'd be a better option. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to someone who posted a comment and then deleted it, I've figured out my own problem. I just had to replace my main call with this:

```
setDeck = new JButton("Set Deck");
  setDeck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        WriteHtmlCardDatabase w = new WriteHtmlCardDatabase();
        w.main(null);
     }
  });
```

Thank you!